# Please make post lockedness meta-data available in the SEDE

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, locked

My subjective experience is that the count of the mod-locked questions is growing, and I feel this starts to cause more and more troubles with time.

I think, adding some new columns to the SEDE schemas, having this important information, would be likely not a big work, but it would help a lot.

I do not know, how does it work in your prod database, but I think, having a "LockedDate" column in the Posts/PostsWithDeleted table, similar to the CommunityOwnedDate, ClosedDate, DeletionDate columns, would be the best.

Comment: Why and which problems does it cause?

Comment: @Luuklag Some examples: 1) Many times queries result (as side-effect) mostly locked posts. It is painful to click one-by-one them and find the few not locked posts. 2) Many times exactly the lockedness is the important thing, there is no way to filter for that. However, meanwhile Glorfindel explained a way to filter for lockedness, so problem solved.

Comment: Yes, all locks ought to timeout after, say, 5 years. They can always be renewed if something happens that shouldn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure the `LockedDate` exists in the source database, but [as the API exposes it](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question), it might be so.

Anyway, it's already possible to query locked posts, e.g. with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1357458/locked-posts) (note that right now, the locks on the top two hits have expired since the last SEDE update on Sunday morning).

You basically need to search for `PostHistory` records of type 14 (Post Locked), make sure there's no newer record of type 15 (Post Unlocked). Since migration involves the Community user locking the question, I've filtered those out as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, fortunately the PostHistory table contains the data of the lock/unlock events. This results that the following query can get the list of the locked posts:

```
SELECT PostId
FROM PostHistory
WHERE
  Id IN (
    SELECT MAX(Id)
    FROM PostHistory
    WHERE PostHistoryTypeId BETWEEN 14 AND 15
    GROUP BY PostId
  )
  AND
  PostHistoryTypeId = 14
```

It works so that

1. It gets the Id of the last lock or unlock event for all the posts (which have one)
2. Shows only the posts, where the last event is a lock event (to filter out the posts which were locked and then unlocked).

This query runs in 3 seconds on the Stack Overflow PostHistory table.